# how to let the touchesMoved only control one view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, event-handling, uibutton

i create an UIButton on the view,and i want to let the touchesMoved only control the UIButton,not the whole view

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchMoved = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}
```

i want to do like this
if i touch the UIButton,and then the UIButton can be moved with my finger,if i touch other view and my finger is moving on the screen,the UIButton does nothing.
that means the function touchesMoved only has the role of the UIButton,so how can i do it? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume the code you show takes place in your custom view controller subclass, and the `UIButton` is a subview of its view.

Define a simple `BOOL` in your class that you set to `NO` first. Then update it in the event handling methods.

```
// .h
BOOL buttonTouched;

// .m
// in the viewDidLoad
buttonTouched = NO;

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // test wether the button is touched
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchBegan = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(theButton.frame, touchBegan) {
        buttonTouched = YES;
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(buttonTouched) {
        // do it here
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint touchMoved = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(touchMoved.x,
                                     touchMoved.y,
                                     theButton.frame.width,
                                     theButton.frame.height);
        theButton.frame = newFrame;
    }
}

// when the event ends, put the BOOL back to NO
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    buttonTouched = NO;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot,but it still doesn't work.the button can not be moved now.thanks

Comment: if(CGRectContainsPoint(theButton.frame, touchBegan)) {
        buttonTouched = YES;
    }  the code here doesn't not work